# How to set env variable in CAPL code from an incoming signal?

Tags: capl, canoe, canalyzer

I use CANoe and i want to add node that take Signals and change env variables

using CAPL coding of course 
for example:

```
on signal Signal_Name
{
   set env variable = SET;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use,

```
@Env_Variable_Name = 1;
```

For example, I have an environment variable named `Env_DrvDrSw`

```
on key 'a'
{
    @Env_DrvDrSw = 1; 
}
```

But CAPL has a small limitation, since the CAPL is an event based programming, The `on envVar Env_DrvDrSw` part in your CAPL code will be executed after the execution of `on key 'a'` event.
You cannot expect it to work like C language.

Hopefully I clarified your question. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The OP is asking how to set an environemnt variable when a bus signal event is fired, not on a key stroke. But the solution formatting is the same, in the end.
I don't quite get the "limitations" you are talking about: the event that should fire on a state change of a env variable is, of course, fired after said change. I am missing your logic?

Answer (score 0):

<s>There is no `on signal *` procedure in CAPL, due to the fact that signals are always transferred as packets of a message. So,</s> you will end up using something like this:

```
on signal ( LightSwitch::OnOff | MotorSwitch::OnOff )
{
  putValue (yourEnvironmentVariable, this);      // Maybe phys, if applies
}
```

<s>Note that a `on envVar yourEnvironmentVariable/*` is triggered immediately after this call. Finally, the `on envVar *` event is always fired when accessing the environment variable, meaning that it does not care if the actual value assigned to the variable has changed or not.</s>

According to the References, and thanks to @M.Spiller, the procedure is called as soon as one of the signals changes.

Comment: There is `on signal_update` which is called whenever a signal is received. And there is `on signal_change` which is called whenever a signal's value changes. And there is `on signal` which is an alias to `on signal_change`.

Comment: @M.Spiller, you are completely right and I forgot about those functions. I'll do my best to edit the reply today. Thanks for the heads up!